# How to make word triangle in c++ with for loop

Tags: c++

how can I make this type of triangle:
where the size of triangle n = 5;

```
Five Four Three Two One
Five Four Three Two
Five Four Three
Five Four
Five
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
int n;
cout<<"Enter Size of triangle: ";
cin>>n;

for(int i = n; i >= 1; i--){
    for(int j = n; j >= i; j--){
        cout<<j<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: I edited my post
I tried something like this but I have no idea how can I convert numbers to words.

Comment: I think your triangle would be upside down, no? Also, if you know the max value of `n`, you can do a map to link numbers to words.

Comment: yes triangle will upside down

Comment: @ChrisMM ... or even just a `switch` if one really wants to keep things simple.

Comment: how can I link the number to words, It's not clear to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = n; i >= 1; i--){
    for(int j = n; j >= i; j--){
        switch(j) {
            case 0: cout <<"zero"<<; break;
            case 1: cout <<"one"<<; break;
            case 2: cout <<"two"<<; break;
            case 3: cout <<"three"<<; break;
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can get the loop right yourself, so what is left is map numbers to strings. There is no automatic way to do that, but you have to define this mapping yourself. Perhaps the easiest is to use a

```
std::vector<std::string> numbers{ "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "put" ,"more", "numbers", "here" };
```

And then instead of printing the number `j` you print `numbers[j]`. Just take care of indexing: Vector uses zero-based indexing, but the first element is `"One"`.